# If the page changes, will the browser still cache an http request for a <script>?

Tags: javascript, browser, httprequest, browser-cache

Example situation:

The page is loading and there is a large `<script>` tag in the page that the browser makes an http request to fetch the js. If the user clicks on a link that changes the page, will the browser still receive and cache the js script requested?  Or is the connection closed and the response is ignored?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the header of the request and the response of the server, specifically the value of  `Cache-Control`.

If you leave a page before a resource is fully loaded, or it times out, the amount that you were able to download may be cached depending on that value. It may also simply be discarded - or it may do either depending on how long it's been since your initial visit.

These are the client side(request) options:

- Cache-Control: max-age=
- Cache-Control: max-stale[=]
- Cache-Control: min-fresh=
- Cache-Control: no-cache
- Cache-Control: no-store
- Cache-Control: no-transform
- Cache-Control: only-if-cached

And the Server Response Options:

- Cache-Control: must-revalidate
- Cache-Control: no-cache
- Cache-Control: no-store
- Cache-Control: no-transform
- Cache-Control: public
- Cache-Control: private
- Cache-Control: proxy-revalidate
- Cache-Control: max-age=
- Cache-Control: s-maxage=

They're mostly pretty intuitive, but for more information please check out [Cache-Control on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) and some information found within the [developers resource on Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching)